# CGI script downloads instead of running

Tags: python, html, apache2, cgi

I'm running apache2 server. CGIHTTPServer is running in directory **/mnt/hgfs/wind/BTech_BTP/BTP/code/final_code/**. I'm using the url **http://localhost:8000/test/www/adder.html**.

I have three file in ../final_code/test/www directory.

adder.html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Adder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fantastic Adder - Sum Two Numbers<br></h1>
    <br>
    <form action="adder.cgi" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">Number
      1:<input maxlength="60" size="60" value="0" name="x"> <br>
      <br>
      Number 2:<input name="y" value="0" maxlength="60" size="60"><br>
      <br>
      &nbsp; <input value="Find Sum" type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

adder.cgi contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi   # NEW

def main(): # NEW except for the call to processInput
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()      # standard cgi script lines to here!

    # use format of next two lines with YOUR names and default data
    numStr1 = form.getfirst("x", "0") # get the form value associated with form
                                   # name 'x'.  Use default "0" if there is none. 
    numStr2 = form.getfirst("y", "0") # similarly for name 'y'
    contents = processInput(numStr1, numStr2)   # process input into a page
    print(contents)

def processInput(numStr1, numStr2):  
    '''Process input parameters and return the final page as a string.'''
    num1 = int(numStr1) # transform input to output data
    num2 = int(numStr2)
    total = num1+num2
    return fileToStr('additionTemplate.html').format(**locals())

# standard code for future cgi scripts from here on
def fileToStr(fileName): 
    """Return a string containing the contents of the named file."""
    fin = open(fileName); 
    contents = fin.read();  
    fin.close() 
    return contents

try:   # NEW
    print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")   # say generating html
    main() 
except:
    cgi.print_exception()                 # catch and print errors
```

When i hit the submit button in browser, it downloads the adder.cgi file instead of executing it???

Also, if you need to see any configuration file, please do let me know.

Edit1:
this is my apache2.conf file after editing.

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#RemoveHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl .py

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Still not working?

Comment: It is working fine now. I placed adder.cgi in the directory .../www/cgi-bin and made change in adder.html as: **action="/cgi-bin/adder.cgi"**.
**cgi-bin** is the default directory for cgi scripts.

Answer (score 7):

In `/etc/apache2/mods-available` directory you can see the installed modules of apache2. `cgi.load` is the module for CGI files. It is not enabled by default. Use these commands to enable them.

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
$ sudo ln -s ../mods-available/cgi.load
```

Then reload the server

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Note that to enable a module, you can use `a2enmod cgi` and it creates all the necessary soft links for you (for cgid, that's two links...)

Answer (score 4):

You need to teach your Apache installation how to deal with CGI scripts by modifying your .conf file.  Check this [link](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/allow_cgi_scripts_within_the_document_root_of_an_apache_webserver.html) out. If your Apache server doesn't have instructions on how to deal with a .cgi extension then it will treat it as any other plain file on the server (which is to serve the file as a client-side file and not server-side code that should be executed/parsed).

An example configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory /var/www/>
     Options ExecCGI
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Future seekers having the same problem here, it is the steps to set CGI correctly. But usually step number 2 is responsible for downloading your CGI file instead of running it

Make the following changes to your httpd.conf file :

1. Uncomment or add `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so`
2. Find `<IfModule alias_module>` Tag and add your script aliases to tell apache where your cgi directory should be mapped to something like this : `ScriptAlias /gias/cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/gias/cgi-bin/"`
3. Add your `<Directory>` tag to give permission to your directory

   ```
      <Directory "${SRVROOT}/gias/cgi-bin">
         AllowOverride None
         Options None
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   ```

and Thats all!

**NOTE :** if you have multiple CGI, each in different directory then you should use `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` inside a `<IfModule>`

Comment: Don't you need `Options ExecCGI`? (or maybe `Options +ExecCGI`)

Answer (score 0):

I note you have a CGI *with python.*

First: you must install the python module for apache:
In ubuntu for example is:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
```

Next you must configure apache so it can read python files:
Edit  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
and add this lines to end of file: (change /var/www to your document root)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AddHandler mod_python .py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
</Directory>
```

And finally restart apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```